# Encrypted password :$2y$10 and $2y$13

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I have a php(symphony) web application and an android application which access to the same database.The password field in the table is encrypted with symphony with Bcrypt and its value started with  `$2y$13`,I used this code php to encrypt my password entered by the android application:

```php
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $pas_hash= password_hash("$password", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_auth WHERE   password = :pas_hash';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pas_hash', $pas_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount())
    {
        $result="true"; 
    }  
    elseif(!$stmt->rowCount())
    {
        $result="false";
    }

    // send result back to android
    echo $result;
}
```

The problem is that the value of  `pas_hash` started with `$2y$10` and when I used `password_verify()`, this function returns `true` result.
I didn't what's the problem because the final `$result` sent to my android application was `false`.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see that you use `password_verify` at all despite saying that. That's your problem.

Comment: that isn't an encryption, it's a hash.

Comment: you're also using the wrong method

Comment: @Fred-ii- what's the right method ?

Comment: see the answer below and/or read the manuals on php.net

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so `if($stmt->rowCount())` is checking if the amount of rows is null or not, but it is not null, it is 0 because your result returned 0 rows.

Change your statement to `if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)` and that should fix it.

Personally the way you are verifying your user(?) is a bit odd, it would be better to search the person's username, get their password from the database and use password_verify on the password you got from the user and the password you got from the database. This may not suit your functionality but it might aswell so take inspiration from the code below if you wish.

Example:

```
 if(isset($_POST['username'])){

      $username = $_POST['username'] // Or however you get the username.
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_auth WHERE username = :username';
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if(password_verify($password, $result['password'])
      {
         $result="true";    
      }  
      else
      {
            $result="false";
      }
      // send result back to android
      echo $result;

}
```

Comment: You should look at their code again and very carefully. Edit: which you did / edited.

Comment: What am I missing Fred? I'm giving this a once over but no luck. Edit: Oh yes what part are you referring too?

Comment: I edited my comment when I saw your edit. That should work for them. Let's see if they'll accept and/or comment here.

Comment: Oh yes I got thinking it would be a good idea to elaborate on it when I hit submit. Yep hopefully this helps you out mak_doni.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have a problem in my wamp server, I will try to resolve it and if it's ok sure I will accept the result, thank you

Comment: @mak_doni any luck pal? Curious to see if it worked for you.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work,always `$result="false"`.When I tried with `username` only it worked

Comment: @mak_doni I tried it there myself and it worked, can you show us the current code you have to help you pinpoint the problem?